# addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, addeventlistener

I don't know why it stills showing me addEventListerner of null and as you can see below I add window.onload function. it load the page and then it will break again showing me that the eventListener is null. But if I click on the X button in the page the error disappear and my page is return normal, except that the toggle Icon is not clickable again... Whicm means the event is not listening... please spare me some of your time and help me resolve this issue. Thank you

```
       /*==================== SHOW NAVBAR ====================*/
const showMenu = (headerToggle, navbarId) =>{
    const toggleBtn = document.getElementById(headerToggle),
    nav = document.getElementById(navbarId)
    
    // Validate that variables exist
    window.onload=function(){
    if(headerToggle && navbarId){
        toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            // We add the show-menu class to the div tag with the nav__menu class
            nav.classList.toggle('show-menu')
            // change icon
            toggleBtn.classList.toggle('bx-x')
        })
    }
 }
}
showMenu('header-toggle','navbar')

/*==================== LINK ACTIVE ====================*/
const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link')

function colorLink(){
    linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
    this.classList.add('active')
}

linkColor.forEach(l => l.addEventListener('click', colorLink))
```

Comment: Please show the HTML along with the JS as a [mcve] using a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your problem correctly... if you are getting `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` error that means that variable on which you are calling this function is `null`, and I suppose it's coming from this line `toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{`. Make sure `toggleBtn` is not `null`, you can check that by using `console.log(toggleBtn);` before adding listener and then looking into console if it printed `null` or not. It is possible `const toggleBtn = document.getElementById(headerToggle)` can't find element with requested id. You haven't provided your HTML code, so that's only a guess.

Comment: Yes you are right the console.log(toggleBtn) is null, but then it is showing null, because before the page render the eventListener check and found I think that's why... any suggestion on how to debug it

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not well structured, `window.onload` should be wrapping your code rather than the other way round. Also if you add an event listener on click, you'll be adding multiple event listeners and your function will fire multiple times. Try something like this (not tested)

```
const showMenu = (headerToggle, navbarId) => {
    nav.classList.toggle("show-menu");
    // change icon
    toggleBtn.classList.toggle("bx-x");
};

window.onload = function () {
  const toggleBtn = document.getElementById(headerToggle),
  nav = document.getElementById(navbarId);
  if (headerToggle && navbarId) {
    toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", () => showMenu);
  }
  showMenu("header-toggle", "navbar");
};


/*==================== LINK ACTIVE ====================*/
const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll(".nav__link");

function colorLink() {
  linkColor.forEach((l) => l.classList.remove("active"));
  this.classList.add("active");
}

linkColor.forEach((l) => l.addEventListener("click", colorLink));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, I really I appreciate it.  The code Work but it is showing me the closeButton Icon instead of the OpenButtonIcon and still the closeIcon is not clickable